# ¿Dejar solo los últimos 40 mensajes y borrar el resto PHP MYSQLI?

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero que se borren los mensajes, que solo queden los últimos 40 para no sobrecargar nada. ¿Cómo lo hago? esto es lo que tengo:

```
$sql47 = ("SELECT * FROM mensjes WHERE titulo = '$id'");
$q47 = mysqli_query($db, $sql47);
if(mysqli_num_rows($q47) >=40){


}
```

Comment: ID  autoincremental

Comment: y prefieres hacer `if(mysqli_num_rows($q47) >=40` en vez de colocar un limit a la consulta?

Comment: añade un campo timestamp de los mensajes, y haz el limit, coge el resultado más grande y ahí tienes el id> para eliminar.

Comment: No me ha servido nada :C miren la captura de mi base de datos: https://prnt.sc/px4g29

Comment: @Laan, actualice mi respuesta y de paso dejo una demo.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo por que el campo titulo que será un varchar o char le metes un `$id` que me imagino que sea un `int`. Yo crearía un campo id en la tabla que sea autoincrementado (hay una forma de que sea autoincrementado pero que cada vez que se borre un campo si habia `id=1`, `id=2`, `id=3` y borras el `id=2`, el `id=3` pase a ser `id=2` pero no me acuerdo como se llama ese tipo de dato) y luego ejecutaria este comando

```
DELETE FROM TABLA  
WHERE id >=40
```

Lo puedes meter dentro de una función que cada X tiempo se ejecute. Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: No entendí nada...

Comment: 1. Crear un campo id en la tabla que deseas eliminar los mensajes.  2.Hacer el DELETE ... que te puse arriba y ya.                                         3. SI quieres/debes mete ese DELETE en una funcion que se ejecute cada X tiempo y te borre los registros o más facil crear un boton y cada vez que le des te vaya ahí y te borre los registros.

Comment: Pero, yo  creo que no me sirve, porque es que ahí se guardan los mensajes de todos los chats, entonces crea muchísimas ids

Comment: Crea un id por cada registro de la tabla, un comentario un id, además que más da que tenga 3 registros como 300, lo importante es que te queden los que quieras

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar tu query por un delete con limit

```
$query = "DELETE FROM mensajes WHERE titulo='{$id}' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 40, (SELECT count(*) FROM mensajes)";
```

De esta manera obtienes el total de registros para tener un limit final, el limit inicial sera de 40 que deberan estar ordenados descendientemente.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que podrías aplicar sería:

- Buscar los `ID`s de los 40 primeros registros ordenados por su `ID` descendente.
- Luego borrar aquellos registros cuyo `ID` sea distinto de los ya obtenidos.

#### Ejemplo:

```
DELETE 
FROM mensajes 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id 
        FROM mensajes 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 40
    ) AS t
)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfe783/1/0)</kbd>

#### Créditos

- [Respuesta original SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124492/3791844)